# Python/MySQLdb import from CSV with data encapsulation

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I have been using WAMP to ingest some csv logs, and wanted to move to a more automated process by scripting some of the routine actions I need to take.

I was using the direct CSV import function in PHPmyadmin to handle the dialect and specifics of the CSV.

I have written an uploader in Python, using MySQLdb that parses the log file, however as the logs contain some unhelpful chars, I am finding that I need to do lots of running around sanitizing inputs where I probably don't want to be...

Example, the log is some data from a directory scanner, and I have no control over the folder naming conventions folks use. I have this folder:-

```
"C:\user\NZ Business Roundtable_Download_13Feb2013, 400 Access"
```

and the `,`char is being read as a new field marker (it is csv after all). What I actually want it to do is to ignore all text inside the quote marks:- `"......"`

I see a similar issue with `'` chars, and I'm sure there will be more.

I found this:- http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2345/import_csv_file_directly_into_mysql/ that shows how I could script the Python to function like the PHPmyadmin load routine. Mainly using this snippet:

```
load data local infile 'uniq.csv' into table tblUniq fields terminated by ','
enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\n'
(uniqName, uniqCity, uniqComments)
```

However there is some in depth processing and changes to the table that I would like to protect that I have already scripted, so wondered if there was a way to "tell" MySQL that I want to use `""` as text encapsulation. The main processing I want to protect is that I give it a specific table name when creating the new table, and use that throughout the rest of the processing.

Example of my table maker script:-

```
def make_table(self):
    query ="DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `atl`.`{}`".format(self.table)
    self.cur.execute(query)
    query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `atl`.`{}` (`PK` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, `ID` varchar(10), `PARENT_ID` varchar(10), `URI` varchar(284), \
        `FILE_PATH` varchar(230), `NAME` varchar(125), `METHOD` varchar(9), `STATUS` varchar(4), `SIZE` varchar(9), \
        `TYPE` varchar(9), `EXT` varchar(11), `LAST_MODIFIED` varchar(19), `EXTENSION_MISMATCH` varchar(20), `MD5_HASH` varchar(32), \
        `FORMAT_COUNT` varchar(2), `PUID` varchar(9), `MIME_TYPE` varchar(71), `FORMAT_NAME` varchar(59), `FORMAT_VERSION` varchar(7), \
        `delete_flag` tinyint, `delete_reason` VARCHAR(80), `move_flag` TINYINT, `move_reason` VARCHAR(80), \
        `ext_change_flag` TINYINT, `ext_change_reason` VARCHAR(80), `ext_change_value` VARCHAR(4), `fname_change_flag` TINYINT, `fname_change_reason` VARCHAR(80),\
        `fname_change_value` VARCHAR(80))".format(self.table)
    self.cur.execute(query)
    self.mydb.commit()
```

Example of my ingest script:-

```
 def ingest_row(self, row):
    query = "insert"
    # Prepare SQL query to INSERT a record into the database.
    query = "INSERT INTO `atl`.`{0}` (`ID`, `PARENT_ID`, `URI`, `FILE_PATH`, `NAME`, `METHOD`, `STATUS`, `SIZE`, `TYPE`, `EXT`, \
        `EXTENSION_MISMATCH`, `LAST_MODIFIED`, `MD5_HASH`, `FORMAT_COUNT`, `PUID`, `MIME_TYPE`, `FORMAT_NAME`,  `FORMAT_VERSION`) \
        VALUES ('{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}','{9}','{10}','{11}','{12}','{13}','{14}','{15}','{16}','{17}','{18}')".format(self.table, row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], \
         row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8], row[9], row[10], row[11], row[12], row[13], row[14], row[15], row[16], row[17])
    try:
        self.cur.execute(query)
        self.mydb.commit()
    except:
        print query
        quit()
```

Example of log:-

```
"ID","PARENT_ID","URI","FILE_PATH","NAME","METHOD","STATUS","SIZE","TYPE","EXT","LAST_MODIFIED","EXTENSION_MISMATCH","MD5_HASH","FORMAT_COUNT","PUID","MIME_TYPE","FORMAT_NAME","FORMAT_VERSION"
"1","","file:/C:/jay/NZ%20Business%20Roundtable_Download_13Feb2013,%20400%20Access/","C:\jay\NZ Business Roundtable_Download_13Feb2013, 400 Access","NZ Business Roundtable_Download_13Feb2013, 400 Access",,"Done","","Folder",,"2013-06-28T11:31:36","false",,"",,"","",""
"2","1","file:/C:/jay/NZ%20Business%20Roundtable_Download_13Feb2013,%20400%20Access/1993/","C:\jay\NZ Business Roundtable_Download_13Feb2013, 400 Access\1993","1993",,"Done","","Folder",,"2013-06-28T11:31:36","false",,"",,"","",""
```

Comment: can you provide a sample of what your log looks like?

Comment: Good point. Done, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `SQL prepared statements`. Mixing data and sql code with `format` opens the door for [`SQL injection`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) (which is almost always [1st in the top 25 software flaw / security issue](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/89.html)).

---

example, here is your data:

```
>>> log = """\
... "ID","PARENT_ID","URI","FILE_PATH","NAME","METHOD","STATUS","SIZE","TYPE","EXT","LAST_MODIFIED","EXTENSION_MISMATCH","MD5_HASH","FORMAT_COUNT","PUID","MIME_TYPE","FORMAT_NAME","FORMAT_VERSION"
... "1","","file:/C:/jay/NZ%20Business%20Roundtable_Download_13Feb2013,%20400%20Access/","C:\jay\NZ Business Roundtable_Download_13Feb2013, 400 Access","NZ Business Roundtable_Download_13Feb2013, 400 Access",,"Done","","Folder",,"2013-06-28T11:31:36","false",,"",,"","",""
... "2","1","file:/C:/jay/NZ%20Business%20Roundtable_Download_13Feb2013,%20400%20Access/1993/","C:\jay\NZ Business Roundtable_Download_13Feb2013, 400 Access\1993","1993",,"Done","","Folder",,"2013-06-28T11:31:36","false",,"",,"","",""
... """
```

I don't have the file, so let's pretend I do:

```
>>> import StringIO
>>> logfile = StringIO.StringIO(log)
```

then let's build the query:

```
>>> import csv
>>> csvreader = csv.reader(logfile)
>>> fields = csvreader.next()
>>> 
>>> table = 'mytable'
>>> 
>>> fields_fmt = ', '.join([ '`%s`' % f for f in fields ])
>>> values_fmt = ', '.join(['%s'] * len(fields))
>>> query = "INSERT INTO `atl`.`{0}` ({1}) VALUES ({2})".format(
... #        self.table, fields_fmt, values_fmt)
...         table, fields_fmt, values_fmt)
>>> query
'INSERT INTO `atl`.`mytable` (`ID`, `PARENT_ID`, `URI`, `FILE_PATH`, `NAME`, `METHOD`, `STATUS`, `SIZE`, `TYPE`, `EXT`, `LAST_MODIFIED`, `EXTENSION_MISMATCH`, `MD5_HASH`, `FORMAT_COUNT`, `PUID`, `MIME_TYPE`, `FORMAT_NAME`, `FORMAT_VERSION`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'
```

then if you massage `ingest_row`:

```
def ingest_row(self, row):
    try:
        self.cur.execute(query, row)
        self.mydb.commit()
    except:
        print query
        quit()
```

you can then import the data with:

```
for row in csvreader:
    ingest_row(row)
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I went ahead a changed things around as per your suggestions, and it worked perfectly. I appreciate you time.

Answer (score 1):

**Never** use string formatting, concatenation etc. to build a sql query!

[`dbapi`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) requires from all drivers to support parameterized queries, parameters should be supplied to the `execute` method of the cursor. For `MySQLdb`, whch supports format style parameterisation, it would look like:

```
cursor.execute('insert into sometable values (%s, %s)', ('spam', 'eggs'))
```

The supplied parameters are correctly escaped by the library, so it won't matter if your strings contain characters that must be escaped.

The only exception in your special case would be the table name, as escaping that would produce illegal sql.

Comment: Ahh, OK, thanks. I thought I was being smart by using the string `format`. As its never going outside of my machine I was not concerned with sql injection etc.  In your example, you're giving the `execute` text, not a var, could I do this safely?  `cursor.execute('insert into sometable values (%s, %s)', (row[1], row[2]))`.

Comment: Yes, exactly like that. In this case it's really less about injection, but about correctly escaping the inserted text - but the reason and the solution for both is the same. you don't want to produce illegal sql if one of your records contains a `'`;

Comment: Excellent and understood. Thanks heaps, I will go and revert all the db calls as per your suggestion, and see how I get on! Appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @JayGattuso - By the way, the [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) the post is talking about would rather invole uploading the csv directly to the server and then letting the server import it directly - but in your code you're inserting the data using a python script... Boths should be fine, but if you want to use the first method, you don't really need the second.

Comment: Yupe, understood, I was interested in the text escaping that was being used in the lOAD DATA INFILE method. Thanks.